# Angular 2 / как реализовать запрет маршрутизации при изменении адресной строки

Tags: angular2, angular-routing

Доброго всем времени суток! Выполняю реализацию приложения с использованием **Deployd Server** (**mongodb** база данных) без **back-end**. Вся логика выполняется исключетльно **angular**.

Маршрутизация приложения имеет вид:

```
 export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        redirectTo: "weather",
        pathMatch: "full"
    },
    { path: "weather", component: ClimateComponent},
    { path: "news", component: NewsComponent},
    { path: "login", component: LoginComponent, outlet: "user-router" },
    { path: "registration", component: RegistrationComponent, outlet: "user-router" }
];
```

таким образом, можно изменять адресную строку, к примеру написав:

```
http://localhost:4200/weather(user-router:registration)
```

после чего я перехожу к компоненту с регистрацией. 
Проблема заключается в том, что после авторизации, всё так же можно ввести в адресную строку маршрут к регистрации или авторизации и они откроются.
Как можно решить это? 
Правильно ли будет использовать ***ngIf** для **router-outlet** который содержит ***registration*** и ***login*** или использовать ***ngIf** напрямую в ***registration*** и ***login*** блокируя их содержимое?
Возможно есть более правильное решение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос. Для ограничения доступа к маршрутам можно использовать Guards. Возможно кому-то пригодиться, вот источник: [metanit.com/web/angular2/7.7.php](http://metanit.com/web/angular2/7.7.php)